# 2 sets of mirrored monitors windows 7

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display

I have a graphics card with 2 dvi outputs. I have 2 monitors and a hdmi switch that goes to a hdtv.

I am trying to see if its possible to mirror each dvi output so that each dvi has 2 receiving displays (a monitor and an input port on the hdmi switch)

I bought these hdmi switches that are supposed to mirror an hdmi input. When i try to connect everything it looks like the pc, running windows 7, only sees one monitor and thinks that the tv is another display instead of mirroring the monitor.

Is there another way, such as another graphics card or another switch, that I can get 4 outputs from my pc. That way I can have 2 outputs go to my monitors and 2 outputs going to the hdmi switch.

what I am trying to accomplish is that I want to be able to mirror each monitor on the tv. So if i have inputs 1 and 2 on the hdmi switch, input 1 will mirror my left monitor and input 2 will mirror my right monitor.

I am open to any suggestions.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this setup:

- get two `DVI to 2x DVI` splitters. These will clone DVI output signal to two different displays.
- connect each of your two monitors to one output on your two DVI splitters.
- get two `DVI to HDMI` cables and connect them to the two splitters and two inputs on your HDTV.
- you can now switch on your TV between i.e. `HDMI1` and `HDMI2` to view monitor 1 or 2 respectively on your HDTV.

Your finished setup would look like this:

```
   ------                     /--- DVI to HDMI cable --- HDMI1 input on TV
   |    |                    /
   |    |----> DVI splitter 1 ---- monitor 1
   | PC |
   |    |----> DVI splitter 2 ---- monitor 2
   |    |                    \
   ------                     \--- DVI to HDMI cable --- HDMI2 input on TV
```

This way, you can control which monitor is being mirrored on your TV by simply switching between HDMI inputs on your TV remote control.